# Coreplot slip in ScatterPLot location

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have upgraded to the latest version of Coreplot (1.2) and came across a problem.

My graph has two plots inside it. A bar plot and a scatter plot. The scatter plot is the line representation of bars connected. All worked well in version 1.1 but when I switched 1.2, the Scatter plot seemed to be misplaced. It's kidn of starting from a bit left. Here is the image:

[image]

Those plotsymbols and the whole scatter plot was right in sync with the bar plot (i.e. the symbol was in the middle of the freen bar, not outside of it and symbols were on the gridlines) as it should be. The points that return from `numberForPlot` are the same values.

And here is my `numberForPlot` method just in case:

```
- (NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
if ([plot.identifier isEqual:kBarPlot] )
{
    if (fieldEnum == CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation)
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.intervalStringArray indexOfObject:[allKeys objectAtIndex:idx]]];

    NSArray *activitiesForDate = [activitiesByDate valueForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:idx]];
    double activityAmount = 0.0;
    if (activitiesForDate)
    {
        //compute value
    }

    DebugLog(@"Barplot returning Y= %f forindex = %d", activityAmount, idx);
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:activityAmount];
}
if ([plot.identifier isEqual:kScatterPlot])
{
    NSString *currentDate = [[self activityDatesAsString] objectAtIndex:idx];
    if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX)
    {
        int currentIndex = [self.intervalStringArray indexOfObject:currentDate];
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:currentIndex];
    }


    NSArray *activitiesForDate = [self activitiesForDate:[self.dateFormatter dateFromString:currentDate]];
    float netActivity = 0.0;

    //compute netActvity
    DebugLog(@"SCATTERPLOT returning %@ for index %d", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:netActivity], idx);
    return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:netActivity];
}
return nil;
```

}

Finally, the log output is;

```
SCATTERPLOT returning -8 for index 0
SCATTERPLOT returning -4 for index 1
Barplot returning Y= -8.000000 for  index = 0
Barplot returning Y= -4.000000 for  index = 1
```

**EDIT**: While I had almost finished posting the code here with the problem persisting even  when the scatter plot is alone in the graph. I have found the issue, yet I don't know if it's normal or if it's a bug. The problem lies with `CPTMutableShadow`:

```
CPTScatterPlot *netActivityPlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
   netActivityPlot.identifier = kNetActivityPlot;
   netActivityPlot.title = @"Net Activity";

   CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [[netActivityPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy] autorelease];
   lineStyle.lineWidth              = 2.0;
   lineStyle.lineColor              = _cptNetActivityLineColor;
   netActivityPlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
   netActivityPlot.dataSource    = self;
   CPTMutableShadow *shadow = [CPTMutableShadow shadow];
   shadow.shadowColor = [CPTColor lightGrayColor];
   shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, -2.0);
   shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 4.0f;
   netActivityPlot.shadow = shadow;
   [activityGraph addPlot:netActivityPlot];

   netActivityPlot.plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)activityGraph.defaultPlotSpace;
```

When I remove the shadow, the plot fits on the lines.

Comment: Is this on iOS or Mac OS X? What version? What happens if you resize the window/rotate the device or scroll the graph?

Comment: It's on iPad. And nothing changes on rotation/scrolling/resizing. Hope there is a quick fix although I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you posted. Can you post the setup code for both plots? Do the plots share a plot space, or do you have more than one?

Comment: See edited question. I don't know why but CPTMutableShadow is causing it.

Comment: @EricSkroch any idea what it could be Eric?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Please report it on the Core Plot [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is reportedly a bug. Placed as a new issue on the Core Plot [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).